# Mockito matcher doesn't recognise abstract classes in arguments

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

this is a sample code

```
when(someObject.someMethod(any(AbstractClass.class)).thenReturn(mockvalue);
```

in the above code, it isn't recognising the argument any(AbstractClass.class) and it calls the real method instead of returning the mock value.

Comment: missed a paranthesis after any() ends

Comment: Are you trying to mock a static method here?

Comment: Nope...its not a static method

Comment: just the use of capitals and the word class in SomeClass.someMethod() makes it look like that. I'll edit it for you. So is this object you are calling the .someMethod() method on a mock? If so the real method cannot be called whatever you do...

Comment: Yeah it is obviously a mock

Comment: I mean that's not obvious because you haven't provided any code and if as you say it's calling the real method then it cant be a mock. Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but you are on the wrong track there.

`any( SomeClass.class )` does **NOT** do what you believe it does. It especially does **NOT** check if the argument is a `SomeClass`, see the Javadoc:

> Any kind object, not necessary of the given class. 
>   The class argument is provided only to avoid casting.

If you have a look at the Any class, you will see why:

```
public boolean matches(Object actual) {
    return true;
}
```

So, ANY argument (as the name implies) will be accepted there. In your case, this means that IF the method `someMethod` on that specific `someObject` is called, it WILL return the `mockvalue`, no matter what the actual argument is.

This implies that your problem is somewhere else entirely, for example ...

- Your mock is not correctly injected into the class you are testing (so that the class is using another object and not the mock)
- The method in question isn't actually called (for example there could be another one with a similar signature, etc.).

Hard to say without code. I would ask a new question but provide more code this time.